# jquery template engine, how to bind events

Tags: jquery, templates

Is there any way to pass function to bind into jQuery template engine?
http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/

If I create HTML without template I would do it like this:

```
jQuery("<a>link</a>").click(function(){alert('hi!')}).appendTo( "#forms_container" );
```

how to do this with jQuery templates?

------------EDIT
I found some library here 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

and seems it something like jQuery.live()

Is there any other ways for binding functions to templates, or this way is used as default mostly?

-----------EDIT
Ok, then let it be .delegate. I think for my small task it will be enough, without adding more complexity with Knockout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to Ian's, but a bit different in implementation:

```
jQuery('#forms_container').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
   //Click event, with context (faster)
});
```

This means that all links in the forms_container will have that click event, no matter what changes.  This differs from Ian's (perfectly legitimate) use of `live` in that it has a context, so events don't need to bubble all the way up.  You can accomplish the same thing using `live` (as of 1.4) if you give it context, but I prefer `delegate`'s syntax.

Comment: yeah I'll concur on delegate - every day is a school day (esp for me ;P)

Comment: @llamerr - The performance is identical, provided you give a context to live. live without context is slower than using delegate, or live with context.

Comment: delegate() wouldn't work for me, live() did. Then i realised I was calling the delegate() on the containing element which was dynamically added to the DOM. So, add the delegate() onto the lowest level that isn't dynamically loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Give your link something to identify it by (a class or similar or based on the parent container(s)). then use .live

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div id="xyz"><a class="tmplClick">${link}</a> </div>
</script>
```

then:

```
$('a.tmplClick').live('click',function(){
    alert('clicked in template');
});
```